# Need opinion on synchrozing a project on two computers

Tags: git, version-control

So I'm frequently working from home. We use a gitlab server in my workplace but I don't want to push my changes to gitlab, just so I can work from home.

I've tried using dropbox but the issue with dropbox is that I can't choose which files to not sync(as far as I know).

Currently I'm working on a Java project so dropbox trys to sync all the files in /target/. I'm also in linux, so I've did a syslink to the folder.

I'm also not sure if I can push these changes to a private repo hosted on github.

These what have come to my mind. What would be the best solution to this problem? As seamless as possible would be the best.

Comment: Do you mean you have two different remote repository? If so, you can choose repository you want to push files to.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to push your changes? I often time do just `work in progress` commits and pushes on my feature branch just for this reason. If you want to keep you commit messages clean you can always ammend your messages afterwards.

Comment: The issue with this is, sometimes I'm lazy and I don't write much code.(also still a junior coder, a bit slow) Don't want to look like I'm doing less job than others.

Comment: We have a gitlab server in our company. And I also have my own github account. Can I switch between these easily?

Comment: @Arimao gitlab and github are just frontend for git. Git supports multiple remotes. You can add additional remotes to your local clone and push and pull from each as much as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a branch and merge it later. That might fix your problem. This might have the advantage that other people can follow your train of thought.

Comment: The issue with this is, sometimes I'm lazy and I don't write much code.(also still a junior coder, a bit slow) Don't want to look like I'm doing less job than others.

Comment: @Arimao To be quite direct: That's a very silly reason. Commit and push what you got. Developers should not be evaluated in LOC anyway, yet refraining from committing in order to not appear lazy is more harming to your career then little commits.

Comment: I've decided to do that k0pernikus. Thanks a lot.